# Bootstrap table resize/reorganize for col-sm

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm new in Bootstrap and tables and I have a table that I've been using it as legend for a chart:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12" id="chart1" style="display:none; border: 1px solid lightgray; padding-top:2%">
    <h3 style="text-align:center"><b>MY CHART</b></h3>
    <div id="chart" style="width:100%; min-height:500px"></div>
    <div id="myLegend" style="width:70%; height:40px;  margin: 0 auto;" class="row">
       <table style="font-size:18px; color:#545454">
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding: 1px">
                         <div style="width:4px; height:0; border: 5px solid rgb(145,207,80); overflow: hidden"></div>
                    </div>
                 </td>
                 <td>First Val</td>
                 <td>
                    <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding: 1px">
                         <div style="width:4px; height:0; border: 5px solid rgb(112,171,70); overflow: hidden"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>Second Val</td>
                <td>
                    <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding: 1px">
                       <div style="width:4px; height:0; border: 5px solid rgb(255,191,0); overflow: hidden"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>Third Val</td>
                <td>
                    <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding: 1px">
                         <div style="width:4px; height:0; border: 5px solid rgb(255,0,0); overflow: hidden"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>Forth Val</td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

On bigger screens the legend looks ok but when the screen is smaller but still bigger than col-sm the table gets outside the div with id `chart1` and I need it to somehow resize/reorganize into two rows to fit the div. I've tried using `table-responsive` but it adds a horizontal scroll and that's not good. 
Is there a way to make the table content fit when the screen size changes?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: @Prajwal Bootstrap 4

Comment: why re you using table for that. you can achieve it using divs. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built it for you here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PXvNvz

What you seem to be missing is the table class:

```
<table class="table"></table>
```

I have also moved your row class which you had myLegend div to the top of the document as it doesn't look like you need it below

EDIT:

I built what I think you are trying to do a different way which might be better, this is how I would go about it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXorXQ?editors=1000

Answer (score 2):

You can refer these knowledge about the grid system.

> The Bootstrap grid system has four classes: 
>   xs (for phones - screens less than 768px wide) 
>   sm (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide) 
>   md (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide) 
>   lg (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide)

If you want your customization, you can overwrite X percentage in default css file bootstrap.min.css

> @media (min-width: 992px) .col-md-4 { 
>       width: X%; }